# Trying to Display Contents from a Text File Using Ajax

Tags: html, ajax

I'm trying to get this assignment to work, but I haven't had much success yet. When the user chooses a country from the drop-down, it's supposed to go to the server and get 1 of 4 text files called usa.txt, Canada.txt, mexico.txt, or Russia.txt and display the content to my webpage. (Each file has a short list of cities in it) Is there something I'm missing? I know I have to make an http request, but all that's displaying now is the drop-down menu. I know that I might need if-else statements in here as well, but I don't know where to put those. Can somebody please help? Apparently the text files are in the link below.

```
 http://157.201.194.254/~ercanbracks    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <!-- This is assign09.html -->
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> Ajax </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadXMLDoc(){
            var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("population").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","usa.txt",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Countries</h1>
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <form name="submission" action="">
        <select name="population" onchange="loadXMLDoc(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select a country:</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="russia">Russia</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="population"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The "network" tab in developer tools can be really handy when learning AJAX.  Also be sure to right-click in the console and tick "Log XMLHTTPRequests" (or similar).

Comment: Hmmmm its not showing me anything...

Comment: @CSStudent — What about the JS console? An errors there? Are you opening the developer tools before you trigger the JS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, you can't open directly point a text file as part of an AJAX request. You need to direct the request to the server page which will read any one of the files (usa.txt, russia.txt, etc.,) and send the contents back as response.

The error is at line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","usa.txt",true);
```

It should be like:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","respond.php?fname=usa.txt",true);
```

Refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to get an idea about how to send a request to the server. I hope you have deployed the webpage(here mentioned as respond.php) in a server like Tomcat and you have a server php/jsp/asp page to receive the request from client and process it.

Comment: That's nonsense. HTTP servers are quite capable of serving up static text files in response to a request for one.

Comment: @Quentin In order to serve the context of the question i mentioned that, i know HTTP servers can serve static text files. The intention of question was to get the contents of the files (usa.txt, russia.txt etc.,) as response, not the files themselves.

Comment: And requesting `usa.txt` from the server will give you the contents of `usa.txt`. A "file" is just a means of storing that content with some metadata on a disk. You only ever get the content (with some metadata in the HTTP header) over HTTP.

Comment: @Quentin I apologize since i haven't seen direct request of text files inside a AJAX request, i thought that could be the reason.